# How to execute a sql resultset from a table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I have a simple query

```sql
SELECT 'kill ' + '''' + session_id + '''' FROM sys.dm_pdw_waits
where object_name like 'dw_prd.F%'

union

SELECT 'kill ' + '''' + session_id + '''' FROM sys.dm_pdw_waits
where object_name like 'dw_prd.D%'
```

This is the resultset

[image]

I want to execute the result set as is, meaning all the kills should execute. I tried making this a variable and executing it but it doesn't execute

What's the easiest way to execute this result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use dynamic SQL here. One method would be to aggregate the strings, and then execute it as one batch. According to the documentation, Azure Synapse supports both `STRING_AGG` and `sys.sp_executesql`, however, I have no way of checking this actually works:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(N'KILL ' + QUOTENAME(session_id, N'''') + N';',@CRLF)
FROM sys.dm_pdw_waits
WHERE object_name LIKE 'dw_prd.[FD]%';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, simple and quick. Now I can run this before I kick off my adf pipelines because we currently have blocks on our warehouse tables because multiple people create their own reports directly from this warehouse IE powerbi, tableau. Much appreciated Larnu